# MessageBox behavior in similar projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have two Multi-Byte Character Set MFC projects - `A` and `B`.  In both of them I have placed `MessageBox("hello");` code line.

Project `A` is happy about that - compiles and runs without problems. And this is strange. If I press F12 to navigate to its definition it goes to `WinUser.h` line `#define MessageBox  MessageBoxA`. Function `MessageBoxA` takes  4 parameters. If I do trace I I'm getting to wincore.cpp line

`int CWnd::MessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszText, LPCTSTR lpszCaption, UINT nType)`

Two last parameters are NULL's.

Project `B` compiler just reports error and not compiles.

```
 'MessageBoxA' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

How to understand why project `A` compiles without problems? I suppose this is linker trick, but how to manage such a things?

`Show includes` shows nothing informative since wincore.cpp is not header.

Answer (score 2):

From inside a `CWnd` derivations, the `MessageBox` goes to the [`CWnd::MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eebkf6f.aspx).

But if you in other class, which does not inherit `CWnd`. you call to the global [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), which have one more argument, and you should give the window handle (or null) as the first parameter.